# How to set some space between the colorbar and the image

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to set some space between the image and the colorbar,  I have tried the pad but do nothing, so...
This is the image I have:
[image]

and this is the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.size']=35
x = np.arange(0,16,1)
yx= np.linspace(-50,0,38)
mx = np.random.rand(15,38)
m2 = np.linspace(0,6,38)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,30))
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)


cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=2)

im = ax.pcolor(x,yx,mx.T,norm=LogNorm(0.1, 100),cmap= 'jet')
cbar = fig.colorbar(im,pad = 2,cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator())  # <- Why? See above.
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Resistividade \u03C1 [ohm.m]', rotation=270)
ax2=ax.twiny()
ax2.plot(m2,yx,'k--',linewidth=10)
#ax2.set_xlim([0,60])
ax2.set_xlabel('Resistividade \u03C1 [ohm.m]')
ax.set_xlabel('Aquisição')
ax.set_ylabel('Profundidade [m]')
#fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('mrec_1'+'.png',bbox_inches = "tight", format='png', dpi=300)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: No, I already tried, from 0.1 to 100 no difference..

Comment: Set `pad=0.7` in`divider.append_axes(..., pad=0.7)`?  It seems `pad` is measured as some kind of fraction.  The documentation isn't very clear.  Probably values larger than 1 get ignored.

Comment: Also, for me, that code doesn't produce that figure

Comment: @DavidG the code produces a similar figure because the data x, yx and mx are different from mine, but the purpose is the same, get some space between colorbar and image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secondary axes occupies all of the space in the figure that is meant for axes. Therefore, no matter what padding you give to the colorbar of `ax`, it wont affect `ax2`.

A hacky-ish solution would be to also spit your secondary axes exactly the same as the primary axes, and then delete the axes where the second colorbar goes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

pad = 0.2  # change the padding. Will affect both axes

im = ax.pcolor(x, yx, mx.T, norm=LogNorm(0.1, 100), cmap='jet')
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=pad)

ax2 = ax.twiny()

ax2.plot(m2, yx, 'k--', linewidth=10)
ax2.set_xlim([0, 60])
ax2.set_xlabel('Resistividade \u03C1 [ohm.m]')
ax.set_xlabel('Aquisição')
ax.set_ylabel('Profundidade [m]')

cbar = fig.colorbar(im,pad = 2,cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator())
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Resistividade \u03C1 [ohm.m]', rotation=270)

secondary_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)  # divide second axes
redundant_cax = secondary_divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=pad)
redundant_cax.remove()  # delete the second (empty) colorbar

plt.show()
```

[image]